# Set default theme on load by attaching a variable at the end of URL

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say a have a dark theme and a light theme.

By default, the website launches with a light theme. User clicks on a button to switch to a dark theme.

Some users prefer the dark theme and don't like to click the button, they want to set the dark theme as default when loading the webpage.

I am trying to do something where a user just needs to attach a method name to the end of the URL to launch the dark theme i.e: www.websitename.com?darktheme

Is this possible?

Current method:

I have a button that toggles the theme:

```
<button class="t-menu__item / js-change-theme">Change Theme</button>
```

I set the default class to the body tag

```
<body class="c-container / t--light">
```

and my js is:

```
 .querySelector('.js-change-theme')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    const body = document.querySelector('body');

    if (body.classList.contains('t--light')) {
      body.classList.remove('t--light');
      body.classList.add('t--dark');
    }
    else {
      body.classList.remove('t--dark');
      body.classList.add('t--light');
    }
  })
;
```

UPDATED with a codepen example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVvyxp

Comment: If you had a link like that : www.websitename.com?theme=dark, you could get the theme name like so : 
`var url = window.location.href;`
`var theme = url.split('theme')[url.split('theme').length - 1].substr(1);`
`console.log(theme)`

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible, you'll have a two-step process, with a litle bit of prep.

1. Prep step:

Switch from a queryString (the `example.com/?darktheme` bit) to a hash (`example.com/#darktheme

2. Detect current mode

You need to read the queryString and see if you're in dark or light theme mode. Set it accordingly and update the body classList, e.g.

```
function updateTheme() {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  // figure out if we're dark or light.
  const theme = window.location.hash.indexOf('darktheme') > -1 ? 'DARK' : 'LIGHT';
  if (dark) {
    body.classList.remove('t--light');
    body.classList.add('t--dark');
  } else {
    body.classList.remove('t--dark');
    body.classList.add('t--light');
  }
}
// Don't forget to run the function for the first time somewhere, e.g. here
updateTheme();
```

3. Observe changes.

With `onhashchange` you can observe changes to the url hash and rerun the update.

```
window.onhashchange = updateTheme;
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: dark is not defined

Comment: Hi Zlatko, I'm confused and can't figure out how to check if it's light or dark in the URL. check out the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVvyxp